# Selected ComboBox to Text Box

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I am working on creating a form which pulls data from a database, and supplies two combo boxes.  ComboBox1 shows Employee name in a "First name Last Name" format. ComboBox2 shows the Employee names in "Last, First" format.  The names are pulling into the combo boxes without any difficulty.

What I am attempting to figure out how to do is once a user selects a name from either of the drop down boxes that it will populate certain text boxes such as, textBox1, textBox2 based on other information from the Query.

I have attempted to use

```
textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

however, I get an error stating: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Here is my current code. I have left out the connection queries to databases and such intentionally.

```
public partial class Employees : Form
{
    public Employees()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Connect to database for Employees Table Headers
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=Server...");

        try {
            myConnection.Open();
            string SqlDataPull = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Lname IS NOT NULL {0} ORDER By Lname", (checkBox1.Checked ? "AND Active='Y'" : ""));
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlDataPull, myConnection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read()) {
                string strEmployee = String.Format("{0}  {1}", dr["Fname"], dr["Lname"]);
                comboBox1.Items.Add(strEmployee);
                textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
                string strEmployee2 = String.Format("{0}, {1}", dr["Lname"], dr["Fname"]);
                comboBox2.Items.Add(strEmployee2);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        } finally {
            if (myConnection != null) {
                myConnection.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main myNewForm = new Main();
        myNewForm.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Reports myNewForm = new Reports();
        myNewForm.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your SelectedIndexChanged event, add the code:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1) {
    textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
  } else {
    textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
  }
}
```

You should probably remove this statement from your while loop:

```
// textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

because you just added the item to the ComboBox items collection, but you don't actually know it's been selected.

Also, make sure you wire the event up:

```
public Employees()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  // yada-yada-yada

  comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
}
```

Comment: This will work for his current implementation, but if the combo box was databound and the "ToString" of the bound object is not the text in the combo box, this could produce unexpected results.

Comment: LarsTech, Thank you for the information.  I have added the code listed abobe but nothing happens when I debug the form. Nothing is being added to textBox1.  It remains blank.  Could this be due to the fact that the ComboBox is being populated from an SQL query?

Comment: @ChrisTurner Then the event wasn't wired up.  I updated the example.  You can also to this from the designer by selecting the ComboBox control, press the lightning bolt icon from the Properies window, and double-clicing on the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Answer (score 6):

If all you need is the text, you can simply use:

```
textBox1.Text = comboBox1.Text;
```

Comment: I would LOVE to know the source and reason for the downvote as this is 100% correct.

Comment: @john Please explain yourself.  comboBox1.Text returns the text currently in the ComboBox, which may either be the textual representation of the selected item OR the freetype of whatever the user entered.  DropDownStyle could be set to DropDownList or validation can be done prior to this statement if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is to use the TEXT value so instead of `textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem;` It should be `textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();` or simply `textBox1.Text = comboBox1.Text`

Comment: @JTorres Indeed. I have been in the world of asp.net for too long. Also, I up voted you out of that down vote.

Comment: I'm in the same boat.  I had to pull up a Form's project just to test it out as it looked right but felt wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can fill a `ComboBox` with items of any type (not just `string`) the `SelectedItem` property has a type of `object`. If you inserted `strings` you can retrieve them by casting

```
string s = (string)myComboBox.SelectedItem;
```

If you added items of some other type like a class `Person`, you can either retrieve this object or get its string or some property with

```
Person p = (Person)myComboBox.SelectedItem;
string s = myComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
string lastName = ((Person)myComboBox.SelectedItem).LastName;
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatly you can't do this:

```
textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

because the result is also path:

```
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Citroen
```

You need only value for example Citroen

So problem can be resolved by searching for string like this:

```
      string auto = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
      int index = auto.IndexOf(" ");
      carModel.Text = auto.Substring(index+1);
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use:

`textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.Text` to get the text part of the item.

`SelectedItem` is an object and you're trying to assign it to the `Text` property of the text box.

Comment: Thank you.  I am new to learning C#; how do I define that the information within the ComboBox is Text?  I edited the line as you suggested; however, now i get the error:Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: SelectedItem is of type "object" and does not have a property called "Text"

Comment: You should probably use @LarsTech's code for your current implementation.

Comment: @john I believe you're thinking of an ASP.NET `DropDownList`, which uses `ListItem` objects which have a `Text` property.